# .htacces mod_rewrite optional parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To have nice URLs I edited my .htacces file

```
domain.com/category/content
```

should be redirected to

```
domain.com/index.php?category=cat&content=cont
```

this works fine with this line

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?category=$1&content=$2 [L]
```

but

```
domain.com/category
```

should be redirected to

```
domain.com/index.php?category=cat
```

to display the contents of the whole category

I'm sure this is easy to solve but it is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?category=$1&content=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That does, that i get a 500 Internal Server Error error even on the domains root